# comparing two rows in trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL 9.3

I'm trying to compare between `OLD` and `New` in a trigger.
I know I can compare one column at a time with `if old.name is distinct from new.name then`.
However my situation is more complex. I have 35 columns. The trigger porpuse is to check if `UPDATE` statment can be done or not. 3 of the columns are always allowed but the rest are sometimes allowed and sometimes not.

Table name is: `customers`

Allowed:

```
customername
entrydate
entrynotes
```

So for example if the update is on `customername` and `entrydate` the trigger does nothing. if it's on `entrydate` and `phone` the trigger doesn't allow the update. So my goal is to get a list of the columns that are about to be updated in the trigger.
Basicly it's all the `new.column_name <> old.column_name`

```
CREATE TRIGGER customerreview
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON customers FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE checkdata();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkdata()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
....
    for row in 
        select key, value
        from jsonb_each_text(row_to_json(old)) jo
        join jsonb_each_text(row_to_json(new)) jn on (jo.key = jn.key)
        where jo.value <> jn.value
    loop
        IF row.key not in ('customername','entrydate','entrynotes') then
                    do something
                END IF;
....
$BODY$
```

However i get error:

> ERROR:  function jsonb_each_text(customers) does not exist LINE 21:
>   from jsonb_each_text(old) jo

What can I do?

Comment: Postgres 9.3 does not have JSONB and thus does not have any `jsonb_xxx` functions. You either need to upgrade to 9.5 or use the `json_xxx` function available in 9.3: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is there another way to do what I want to do?

Comment: As I said: you need to use `json_each_text()` instead of `jsonb_each_text()`

Comment: [comparing two rows in trigger](http://pastebin.com/pBXQJhMq)